# How to signal a test to stop in TestNG?

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I have written tests for my windows based application in [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html). Sometimes my tests will result in BSOD of windows, so the test will run waiting for the Windows to be up till timeout and fail.

I have written  a [Listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) for BSOD detection and handling, so that whenever the test starts the BSOD detector will start as listener and handle if the BSOD occurs. But still I have no way to notify my test that it has to halt. It still continues to execute till timeout.

How can solve this problem? Is there a way to notify the test to terminate it from Listener?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop TestNG executioner when exception occures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917223/how-to-stop-testng-executioner-when-exception-occures)

Comment: @JasonC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917223/how-to-stop-testng-executioner-when-exception-occures  dealt with different type of problem. The OP wanted the test to be skipped if some exception occurs. Here I want to stop the test which is already executing.

Comment: Are you testing to see how your application behaves during a BSOD? Shouldn't you rather not get a BSOD?

Comment: @radimpe True, I shouldn't be getting BSOD. But sometimes my tests will write corrupted values into Registry to see how the application behaves. Such negative tests sometimes causes BSOD.

Comment: Just a little curious here, have you automated the windows application using any framework in java itself like robot or something? Or is it something else?

Comment: @Bharathi I have retracted my duplicate close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be out of luck.

The discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/BkIQeI0l0lc clearly indicates that, as of August 2012 there was no way to stop a running test suite.

That combined with a much older post (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/FhC3rqs1yDM) from February 2010 suggests it has been a shortcoming of TestNG for a while.

The current TestNG documentation does not describe any methods for stopping the suite.

From what I can see in the source code (although I have not traced through all paths) at https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java, it simply creates new tasks for each test and runs them, providing no way to break early.

Perhaps you could modify your tests to have access to some flag that indicates if subsequent tests should be skipped (triggered by, e.g., the BSOD detector). Then all of your subsequent tests are responsible for indicating themselves as skipped if this flag is set. It might not be ideal, but one way to think about it is: Any test *should* be skipped if a BSOD (or other terminal event) was detected prior to that test.

You could request this feature on the TestNG Google Group (linked above). If you are so inclined, you could also perhaps customize the TestNG source.